# Bootstrap datetime picker calendar not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Trying to use the bootstrap datetime picker with a modal, and I can get it to load, looks great, but when I try and click the calendar icon, the calendar does not show up, I have checked all my dependencies, file load order, conflicts, etc.. but nada here is my code

**html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-  theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/timesheet.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../images/calendar.png">
    <title>Time Sheet</title>
</head>

<body background="../images/Art-White-Hours-Wallpaper-HD-197.jpg">
    <div>
        <%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/navbarfragment.jspf"%>
            <%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/loginmodal.jspf"%>
                <%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/edittimemodal.jspf"%>
                    <%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/timereport.jspf"%>

    </div>
    <h1 class="titlebacktext">This is a time sheet</h1>
    <div class="titleback"></div>




    <%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/footerfragment.jspf"%>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/moment.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/timesheet.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**javascript file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*jQuery(function($){*/

    $(function() {

        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: "7/4/2015"
        });
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: "7/4/2015"
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function(e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function(e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
});
```

forgot to add this before but here is the edittimemodal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edittime-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content entertime">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please Enter a Start and End Time</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class='col-md-5'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-5'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Time</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Annoyingly I am getting no Errors, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Tried adding an `onclick` to it and still nothing, then again maybe I just have something written wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: Q: Why do you have two nested DOM ready handlers? `$(function(){` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`? (your formatting of the code threw me for a second, so deleted my answer for now). The commented out version `jQuery(function($){` is actually the safest option as it provides a locally scoped $ for jQuery.

Comment: apologies for that being harder to read commented out and the other being there, just trying to trouble shoot and thought that might be an issue, but I left it there to show another thing I have tried.

Comment: can you try putting moment.js after the bootstrap.min.js. try putting it like this <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> here's a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lth82qm9/

Comment: tried it, one thing I did notice is that on mine the default values are loading either, but still not working, also made sure adblock etc.. is turned off.  And I tried it without the extra $(function() { and also with the jQuery(function($){

Comment: did u try clicking the calendar icon as well? the calendar is not loading when u click on the textbox. it only loads when u click on the calendar icon. also can u share the html for the datepicker textboxes?

Comment: It is the clicking the icon and failure to load the default values in the form that I am having trouble with, the datepicker textboxes are part of the moment.js/datetimepicker css items, think it might be how I have it nested in a modal, because just pasting the body into fiddle works

Comment: can you try adding a z-index property to datepicker and see if it works? try this <style>
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
</style>

Comment: no change, tried .datetimepicker, datepicker, and entertime, .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget,  tried it removing my css...still the same.

Comment: even with the modal, it works fine. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lth82qm9/2/

Comment: you are correct, works fine everywhere... except in my page, going to do some more research and debugging and come back either with an answer or more information, ty all for your help so far.

Comment: yeah. you can try putting a console.log( $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker()) and see if it returns anything in the console. also try removing the other datepicker and see if it works. try putting one at at time and if it works then put the other datepicker

Comment: https://github.com/rhelvey/timesheetcomresource  threw it up in github, still running into the same issue.

Comment: the console.log was a fantastic idea! i was just using alert boxes, now the error that I get is that... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined... which being pretty new I have not run into before, going to read up on it a bit

Comment: do u know where exactly is it giving this error? the console will show u the line no. where you're getting the error. try clicking on it to see what is causing this issue

Comment: It appears you are getting an error in code that is not shown. If any uncaught exception occurs in the page, subsequent JavaScript/jQuery will not run.

Comment: Sushi, was getting the uncaught from the show() that I tried to use from the suggested code took it out and no error, either way still having the original issue.

Comment: SOLVED!!! some how I had an outdated version of moment.js and the corresponding css file, only found it by removing each file and replacing it.  Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this one was really strange, but after stripping everything down, I simply deleted all the JS files and re-imported them, and then it worked... so strange and really frustrating, but that was the answer.... I guess one of the files when downloaded had an error because I got them from the same places...